# What is the correct timing when cooking spaghetti sauce from minced meat and prepared tomato sauce?

Tags: sauce, spaghetti

First, after adding a little oil in the pot, when do I add the minced meat? Then how long do I leave it?

Also, when should I add the sauce? (I use a spaghetti sauce already prepared with all stuff in it.)

Finally: after I add the sauce, how long should I leave it before in the pot before I serve the minced meat sauce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the meat when the oil is hot, then break it up with a spatula or wooden spoon. Cook it until it is completely browned. You may need to pour off quite a bit of liquid that comes out of the mince.

The jar of spaghetti sauce should tell you how long it needs to be cooked for.

Answer (score 0):

Add oil enough to make a 2mm layer on the bottom of the pan then onion,
celery and carrot and let cook (not fry) until onion get golden, sprinkle 1 dL of wine and let it "vanish" (sorry I cant translate "sfumare" in cooking terms) then add the meat (mixing some times) and cook it until all meat changes colour to light brown, then add the tomato sauce, half glass of milk per kilo of meat and cook on appropriate heat for at least 2 hours mixing every five minutes.

Comment: I suspect that the 'sfumare' is equivalent to the French 'au sec': https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-does-au-sec-995570 .  And your instructions would make for a really good bolognese, but if someone's working from ground meat + pre-made sauce, and asking about timing, they might not be looking for something that's going to take 2+ hours.